# Assign image resource in an image view with string

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, picasso

**(1)** I am using `recyleview` to fetch image, text & audio file from API. For text I used volley & for image use picasso, what I will use for audio file.

**(2)** after fetch the image & text when apply `onclicklistener` pass the info to another activity. Can pass only text not images.

What I need to do to solve this problem?

this is adapter part

```
viewHolder.textViewStory.setText(banglaItem.getStoryName());
viewHolder.textViewWritter.setText(banglaItem.getWritterName());

        Picasso.get().load(banglaItem.getStoryImage()).fit().into(viewHolder.imageView);

        viewHolder.linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,AudioActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("storyName",banglaItem.getStoryName());
                intent.putExtra("storyImage",banglaItem.getStoryImage());

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

this is the new activity part

```
public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView name;
    ImageView image;
    String nameStory;
    String imageStory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

        name = findViewById(R.id.audioName);
        image = findViewById(R.id.audioImage);

        nameStory = getIntent().getStringExtra("storyName");
        imageStory = getIntent().getStringExtra("storyImage");

        name.setText(nameStory);
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageStory,"drawable", getPackageName());
        image.setImageResource(resourceId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried by editing the question and pasting your code!

Comment: please check it again 
it's very urgent

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1.)**  if you have complete url of your audio file then you can directly stream audio file using media player classes provided by android.

**(2.)** you are passing `storyImage`  in next activity ,which is a url that you get from api. so you have to find same on next activity i.e

```
   TextView name;
   ImageView image;
   String nameStory;
   String imageStory;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

   name = findViewById(R.id.audioName);
   image = findViewById(R.id.audioImage);

   nameStory = getIntent().getStringExtra("storyName");
   imageStory = getIntent().getStringExtra("storyImage");

   name.setText(nameStory);
   Picasso.get().load(imageStory).fit().into(image);
   //here image story contain url that you sent through first activity. As picasso uses cache, it will load (already loaded image in first activity) very smoothly from it cache.
}
```

Comment: you deserve it for the help
but I can't fetch audio file from api
will you please help about it?

Comment: quick question, what is your motive with audio file, 1.) you want to stream audio file or 2.) download that file .

Comment: only stream & play in different scren

Comment: MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        mp.reset();
        return false;
    }
});

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});

try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://youraudiourl");
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}

Comment: Keep in mind the Android MediaPlayer class will only play supported formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: when I want to retrive audio file
i face this problm
will u please check it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037754/fetch-audio-file-source-from-api